# Starting Chrome without any window

Tags: google-chrome, boot

I have a situation where I want to start Google Chrome browser without any window appearing in Linux. My intention is to launch it faster than it already does.

I've noticed that if Chrome is already running, then opening any new windows happens very quickly; I thought I'll keep it running in the background and when needed open a new window by clicking its icon.

I've checked almost all command line switches in the Chrome source code but couldn't find anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Just load it normally and keep it minimized.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for it opening so fast is because it already has the program's data in memory.

The best way to go about this would be not to launch Chrome 'invisibly', but use `readahead`. There is some documentation [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readahead) and [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AutomaticBootAndApplicationPrefetchingSpec).

Comment: Thanks but readhead system call applies while developing application. Moreover, I am sure its not a matter of one file. The chrome session (so to say) will have many libraries, configs that will remain loaded. Its just that it adds newly created windows to this new session